# what is dask and how is it different from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dask

1. Can any one explain how to rectify this error
2. Where do i get a detailed info of dask
3. Can it replace pandas.
4. How is it different from other dataframes, is it fast in processing

Code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd      
df = dd.demo.make_timeseries('2000-01-01', '2000-12-31', freq='10s', partition_freq='1M',dtypes={'name': str, 'id': int, 'x': float, 'y': float})            
print df
```

o/p:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/divya.nagandla/PycharmProjects/python/supressions1/dask.py", line 1, in 
>       import dask.dataframe as dd
>     File "C:\Users\divya.nagandla\PycharmProjects\python\supressions1\dask.py", line 1, in

import dask.dataframe as dd
ImportError: No module named dataframe

Comment: use this link: https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/. Before using dask you have to install it:)

Comment: All these i have installed and getting successfully installed , but while running the program getting the same error as i have posted above    
 
pip install "dask[complete]";pip install dask;pip install "dask[dataframe]"

Comment: I think your environment variable refers some other python variant. It may be conda

Comment: all these days i have been installing every import using pip install .never got the error .

Comment: import dask.dataframe as dd ImportError: No module named dataframe
this error's root cause is package not installed properly.

Comment: can some one help how to get over the error, what are the possibilities and what can i do

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install dask[dataframe]
```

you can also install complete dask package

```
pip install dask[complete]
```

[installation guide](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/install.html#pip)

for more light on dask follow below [links](https://github.com/dask/dask-tutorial)

1. https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/_downloads/daskcheatsheet.pdf
2. Details info on dask https://github.com/dask/dask-tutorial