# Convert two CSV tables with one-to-many relation to JSON with embedded list of subdocuments

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have two CSV files which have one-to-many relation between them.

`main.csv`:

```
"main_id","name"
"1","foobar"
```

`attributes.csv`:

```
"id","main_id","name","value","updated_at"
"100","1","color","red","2020-10-10"
"101","1","shape","square","2020-10-10"
"102","1","size","small","2020-10-10"
```

I would like to convert this to JSON of this structure:

```
[
  {
    "main_id": "1",
    "name": "foobar",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "id": "100",
        "name": "color",
        "value": "red",
        "updated_at": "2020-10-10"
      },
      {
        "id": "101",
        "name": "shape",
        "value": "square",
        "updated_at": "2020-10-10"
      },
      {
        "id": "103",
        "name": "size",
        "value": "small",
        "updated_at": "2020-10-10"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried using Python and Pandas like:

```
import pandas

def transform_group(group):
    group.reset_index(inplace=True)
    group.drop('main_id', axis='columns', inplace=True)
    return group.to_dict(orient='records')

main = pandas.read_csv('main.csv')
attributes = pandas.read_csv('attributes.csv', index_col=0)

attributes = attributes.groupby('main_id').apply(transform_group)
attributes.name = "attributes"

main = main.merge(
    right=attributes,
    on='main_id',
    how='left',
    validate='m:1',
    copy=False,
)

main.to_json('out.json', orient='records', indent=2)
```

It works. But the issue is that it does not seem to scale. When running on my whole dataset I have, I can load individual CSV files without problems, but when trying to modify data structure before calling `to_json`, memory usage explodes.

So is there a more efficient way to do this transformation? Maybe there is some Pandas feature I am missing? Or is there some other library to use? Moreover, use of `apply` seems to be pretty slow here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough problem and we have all felt your pain.

There are three ways I would attack this problem.  First, groupby is slower if you allow pandas to do the break out.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.random.randint(0, 100, 5000), 
                   'name': np.random.randint(0, 100, 5000)})
```

now if you do the standard groupby

```
groups = []
for k, rows in df.groupby('id'):
    groups.append(rows)
```

you will find that

```
groups = defaultdict(lambda: [])
for id, name in df.values:
    groups[id].append((id, name))
```

is about 3 times faster.

The second method is I would use change it to use Dask and the dask parallelization. A discussion about dask is [what is dask and how is it different from pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461126/what-is-dask-and-how-is-it-different-from-pandas/50462000).

The third is algorithmic.  Load up the main file and then by ID, then only load the data for that ID, having multiple bites at what is in memory and what is in disk, then saving out a partial result as it becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

So in my case I was able to load original tables in memory, but doing embedding exploded the size so that it did not fit memory anymore. So I ended up still using Pandas to load CSV files, but then I iteratively generate row by row and saving each row into a separate JSON. This means I do not have a large data structure in the memory for one large JSON.

Another important realization was that it is important to make the related column an index, and that it has to be sorted, so that querying it is fast (because generally there are duplicate entries in the related column).

I made the following two helper functions:

```
def get_related_dict(related_table, label):
    assert related_table.index.is_unique

    if pandas.isna(label):
        return None

    row = related_table.loc[label]

    assert isinstance(row, pandas.Series), label

    result = row.to_dict()
    result[related_table.index.name] = label

    return result


def get_related_list(related_table, label):
    # Important to be more performant when selecting non-unique labels.
    assert related_table.index.is_monotonic_increasing

    try:
        # We use this syntax for always get a DataFrame and not a Series when there is only one row matching.
        return related_table.loc[[label], :].to_dict(orient='records')
    except KeyError:
        return []
```

And then I do:

```
main = pandas.read_csv('main.csv', index_col=0)
attributes = pandas.read_csv('attributes.csv', index_col=1)

# We sort index to be more performant when selecting non-unique labels. We use stable sort.
attributes.sort_index(inplace=True, kind='mergesort')

columns = [main.index.name] + list(main.columns)
for row in main.itertuples(index=True, name=None):
    assert len(columns) == len(row)
    data = dict(zip(columns, row))

    data['attributes'] = get_related_list(attributes, data['main_id'])

    json.dump(data, sys.stdout, indent=2)
    sys.stdout.write("\n")
```